# Entity Framework Migrations not getting applied at all

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, migration

Can someone explain how to access the database the migrations modify? I keep making migrations and reverting back, but I have no idea which database gets modified. I open the SQL object explorer and refresh and sees nothing there, I open the Server Explorer and disconnect all connections and somehow my migrations still get applied. What the hell is wrong with VS2015? It's me or the software isn't working correctly at all?

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to 

the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201511282210132_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201511282210132_Initial.
Running Seed method.
PM> update-database -target:0
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Reverting migrations: [201511282210132_Initial].
Reverting explicit migration: 201511282210132_Initial.
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201511282210132_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201511282210132_Initial.
Running Seed method.
PM> update-database -target:0
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Reverting migrations: [201511282210132_Initial].
Reverting explicit migration: 201511282210132_Initial.
PM> update-database -target:0
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is already at version 0.
PM>
```

Someone told me that if the migrations get applied, it means that VS2015 successfully modified a database, but it doesn't seem to be the case at all.

Maybe something is wrong with my config files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP;Database=API;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings></appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Also, there is no files in App_Data. Someone told me there should be a mdf file, but I can't find anything. Maybe something is wrong with VS2015. Another thing to consider is that I am trying to do a tutorial done in VS2013 with VS2015.

Comment: Your connection string says `Server=DESKTOP;Database=API` so you should check `API` database on the `DESKTOP` server.

Comment: there's no table that's getting created, that's the weird thing. I've been hitting my head on the wall because of this. It doesn't make any sense! In the table folder, we only see the folder System Tables and FileTables with no other table than dbo.sysdiagram. I tried doing the same without creating a db a priori and it doesn't work at all. If I create it before doing the migrations, absolutely no changes. I have no idea what's wrong with VS2015.

Comment: Even if you run `update-database` command? Can you post your `Initial` migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- Original Connection String -->
    <!--
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
         Initial Catalog=aspnet-AspnetIdentitySample-20130627083537_2;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    -->
    <!-- New Connection String -->
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
         Initial Catalog=MyAspnetIdentitySample_1;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Ok, so the problem was that I didn't put a connectionString in my constructor. For some reason, in the tutorial it worked without it, but it seems that ASP.NET changed a lot since then, so you should probably make one if you end up with the same problem as I did.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext{
   public MyDbContext() : base("MyConnectionString") { }
}
```

After doing this, just rollback all the migration, delete the migration folder and write in the package management console:

```
>Enable-Migrations
>Add-Migration Initial
>Update-Database
```

These 3 commands should create the database.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following approach for solving the issue.
Open Package manger console and following command

1>Enable-Migrations
already enable
2>Add-Migration Initial
completed
3>Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL......

Solution 1:- I had open  the database and delete the **__MigrationHistory**
and run command update-database command

Solution 2: If 1st solution not work,then delete the all table from database
and run update-database command in management console
your data with structure will be available.

This may solve your issue.

Thanks 
Sameer Bahad

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your project,
2. Build Again (Don't use rebuild),
3. Then run update-database in package manager console.

These 3 steps always work for me without lost any data.

Answer (score 0):

Make the (DAL) project you are working on as a startup project and try again